# Is Chuck Shurley in Season 5 God?

Tags: supernatural

At the end of Season 5 of *Supernatural* Chuck the prophet disappears. Is he God? If yes, why didn't Dean's locket glow? If not, what happened to him? Did he die?

I ask because eventually Kevin became the prophet and they said there's only one prophet.

Answer (score 6):

No one knows for certain.  The writers kept it vague in the show, and have maintained that vagueness in interviews since the end of season 5.

Comment: Are they going to continue this someday?

Comment: @user8157 I can't predict that.  My crystal ball is broken, and is being repaired.

Answer (score 1):

**We don't know**.

It has been deliberately kept vague, as this interview with (then) showrunner Sera Gamble shows:

> **Interviewer**: ...Do you mean Chuck is the obvious
>   answer, or that you really did leave it open?
>
> **Sera**: Don't ask me to squish the God debate! How many TV shows can say their
>   fans are talking about THAT stuff?

**There are a variety of fascinating things that support the argument though:**

1. Chuck created the *Supernatural* books, which mirror the lives of Sam and Dean. When he first "discovers" that his books are real, he says:

> **Chuck**: Well, there's only one explanation. Obviously I'm a god.
>   **Sam**:
>   You're not a god.
>   **Chuck**: How else do you explain it? I write things
>   and then they come to life. Yeah, no, I'm definitely a god. A cruel,
>   cruel, capricious god. The things I put you through – The physical
>   beatings alone.

2. Chuck's writing name is *Carver Edlund*, which is a mashup of *Jeremy Carver* and *Ben Edlund*, who are Supernatural writers - just as they are *gods* over Sam and Dean and the Supernatural show, Chuck could be THE *god within the show.*
3. We learn in [Dark Side of the Moon](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=5.16_Dark_Side_of_the_Moon), from the angel Joshua, that God is in fact on Earth.
4. We learn in [Sympathy for the Devil](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=5.01_Sympathy_for_the_Devil) that Chuck can *feel* the presence of the angel's in the house. However, we later discover from Kevin Tran (a true prophet) that this is *not in fact one of the prophet's powers*.
5. In [Swan Song](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSwan_Song_%2528Supernatural%2529&ei=x6R1VN2xO4yu7Aa764CIDQ&usg=AFQjCNH8AYBYg_UG1QbflxKU-r8OmB8X7w), Chuck is called by Dean, answering the phone "Mistress Magda". This is in reference to a newspaper article on his desk, with a bikini-clad woman called "Miss Magda" he had supposedly invited over. This is also a name very similar to *[Mary Magdalene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Magdalene)*, a followed of Jesus.
6. Also in Swan Song, when the day is "saved", Chuck, dressed all in white, comments on how hard it is to write a good ending, before magically disappearing.

**There are also a variety of fascinating things that go against the argument:**

1. According to Castiel, in [Good God Y'Al](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=5.02_Good_God,_Y%27All)l, Dean's amulet will burn hot in the presence of God - but Chuck shows no reaction to it. (Having said that, Joshua tells Sam in Dark Side of the Moon that "Magic amulet or not, you won't be able to find him".
2. Castiel doesn't recognise God or anything *higher power-esque* about him.

**Other Interesting Info**

The actor who played Chuck, [Rob Benedict](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Rob_Benedict), claimed the character was God and that other members of the cast had asked him how it felt to be God. Footage of that is here:

**Conclusion**

Believe what you will. It doesn't look like we'll ever get a definitive answer, with the show creators preferring to let fans speculate.

Comment: Is answering questions here your job?

Comment: @Travis: Ha! No, I just go on random sprees here and there.

Answer (score 0):

according to the wiki-yes, chuck is God, the creators finally confirmed it a while back.

Comment: user12826 is right it does state that on the wiki http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Chuck_Shurley

Comment: the confirmation is still vague enough to be plausibly deniable, but at the very least the actor who played Chuck thinks he was playing God.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Chuck is was and is God. This was explicitly confirmed in Season 11 Episode 20 "Don't Call me Shurey". He simply chose to hide in plain sight.

Answer (score 0):

The theory is yes, because of the way he disappears at the end of season 5 (in Swan Song) and also because of his appearance in Fan Fiction (season 10). But to this day, none of the actors or other crew members have actually confirmed that theory although we've heard a few of them joke about it.

And they joke about it in the same way that Misha jokes about Destiel, except they rarely go near the idea of Chuck being God. Here's to hoping they tell us next season!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late here, but I'm from the future. 
Fair warning: there are spoilers in here

Chuck is God. The reason the little amulet thing didn't shine is because god himself turned off its ability to detect him so as to carry on undercover. 
He's not dead, far from it. He's alive and kicking and is the guy who the Winchesters, Castiel, and the new incarnation of death are pitted against, together with Lucifer's offspring. 
Chuck is currently working on the finale of his favorite show, Supernatural, which he intends to end in a biblical fashion, Cain and Abel style.